# Does gzopen read the whole file into memory?

Tags: php, gzip

I am trying to read a gzip file line by line (once decoded) to preserve memory limit, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't read the file into memory. If you look at the [documentation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php) you will see that it returns a resource to the archived file. You can then use other function to read a certain amount of data (until the first line delimiter, or a fixed number of bytes, or even the whole file). If you look at the available functions you will see that they are very similar to those from the file API.

**Bonus:** If you want to use the standard file API you can use the [`compress.zlib://`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) wrapper to open the archive.

Comment: Can I use `fgets` once I gzopened the file or do I have to use `gzread` which won't do the same thing?!

Comment: @fire You can use `gzgets` to do the same thing that `fgets` does for normal files.

Comment: @fire see the latest edit for another approach to opening archives.